# Getting the parent object of a function on JS

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to get the parent object of a function? Like which object activated the function?
Here's the JS

```
var ua=false
function toggleUA() {

if (ua==false)

{document.getElementById("ua").src="http://i805.photobucket.com/albums/yy331/NatFan/uamap.png";ua=true;}
else
{document.getElementById("ua").src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Transparent.png";ua=false;} }
```

Here's the HTML

```
<img class="airline" id="ua" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Transparent.png" width="1500" height="744">
<table class="nav">

<tr>

<td class="star" onclick='toggleUA();'>United Airlines</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

So If I wanted to have the table cell change colors when i click it, how would I do that?

Comment: Maybe parent isnt the right word. I want to have the cell change colors when the function is executed, without having to go through the process of assigning the cell an id and having the function search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the safer way is to pass `this` to the function call as the first argument, and then use that to manipulate it. Such as:

```
<td class="star" onclick='toggleUA(this);'>United Airlines</td>
```

And then the Javascript function would be declared as:

```
function toggleUA(obj) {
```

Where `obj` is the `<td>` that was clicked (in case you use this on several `<td>` elements).

Now, normally the way event listeners works is that you can usually reference `this` in the function automatically without having to pass it as an argument, but the way **inline** event handlers works isn't the same, and you need to pass `this`.

UPDATE:

To modify the background color or other style properties, you can use the `.style` property of the element. With this, you should be able to modify any CSS property, and for background color, use:

```
this.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style

Comment: Trying to figure out how i would then change the color. looking through w3schools for a method. Would I use setAttribute? Which method, if any would be appropriate to change the CSS background-color?